# What Javafx element is used for displaying text, such as an ebook page?

Tags: java, javafx

**What Javafx element is used for displaying text, such as an ebook page?**

Perhaps it is a simple matter of terminology, which is why I cannot find a 'google answer' but I would like to create a reading area in javafx, preferably styleable with css.

I see plenty of documentation for 'text area' inputs, but I cannot get anything returned on text blocks.

In case I am unclear, what element could you use to :

- Print out the contents of an ebook, styled/formatted?
- Print out a recipe

Comment: Are you looking for the element called [`Text`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html)? :)

Comment: Its extraordinary I searched so much and never found that.

Comment: A [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) is probably better for some formats with a little work.  .epub is basically just html.

Comment: If you look at `Text`, you should probably also look at [`TextFlow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html)